# Pandas: Filtering rows by the number of occurrences of subgroups

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with ids, their posts, and dates of its publications (rounded up to months). Date is an index. I need to filter out all the ids that have posted less than 100 posts per month and during less than 20 months

The dataframe looks like this:

```
date        id  post    month_year
2017-11-01  123 text1   2017-11
2018-06-01  456 text2   2018-06
2018-06-01  789 text3   2018-09
2019-01-01  112 text4   2019-01
2019-02-01  112 text5   2019-02
2019-03-01  112 text6   2019-03
2019-06-01  112 text7   2018-09
```

To filter ids by the number of posts per month I used this code:

```py
df.groupby(['id', 'date'], as_index=False).filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 100)
```

But I have no clue how to filter by amount of rows in subgroup. When I try to filter by the date only, it counts all the dates in dataframe that are definitely over 20.

Thank you!

P.S. My crarification from the comment: I need people who have been posting regularly 100 posts per month for at least 20 months (I don't need these months in a row, but if they're in a row, that's good, too). For this purpose, I want to filter everybody who has at least 100 posts in a month by the code provided by me above. But I don't know how to drop people who were posting only for 10 months for example (even though each of the months was fruitful enough for at least 100 posts).

Comment: df.groupby(['id', 'date'], as_index=False).filter(lambda x: len(x) <= 20) ?

Comment: you should edit your question and input your table. copy and paste your table in the right location, highlight your table and click the {} button. use indentation to make sure it is aligned correctly

Comment: @Acccumulation  I need people who have been posting regularly 100 posts per month for at least 20 months (I don't need these months in a row, but if they're in a row, that's good, too). For this purpose, I want to filter everybody who has at least 100 posts in a month by the code provided by me above. But I don't know how to drop people who were posting only for 10 months for example (even though each of the months was fruitful enough for at least 100 posts). I hope I have explained it clearer

Comment: @WeNYoBen I'm afraid it's exactly the same code that I wrote above...

Comment: @adhg thx a lot! done

Comment: So if someone posts 100 posts in Jan 2016 and 100 posts in Jan 2018, but not in any other months, that doesn't count (they posted over a period of more than 20 months, but they didn't post in all of those months)?

Comment: @Acccumulation exactly!

Answer (score 0):

I think that a pivot table would be more appropriate than `group_by`.

```
  id_month_pt = pd.pivot_table(
        df, values = 'post', index = 'id', 
        columns = 'month-year', aggfunc = 'count')
  active_months = id_month_pt >= 100
  active_month_counts = active_months.sum(1)
  active_users = active_month_counts >= 20
```

You will now have a Pandas Series `active_users` where the index is the user ids and the values are booleans saying whether that user had at least 20 months of at least 100 posts. You can then use that series to filter the original dataframe.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it shows me ids with my criteria. There is one problem with pivot, it changes dataframe when I want to leave it with the same structure since I need to work with it later. Is it possible somehow to take out the ids that are aligned with the condition and then filter by them my initial dataframe?